# How to use Visual Studio Tools for Git

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012

I am using VS 2012 to test my GIT server.
I install Git on UBUNTU 12.04.
I am trying to use Visual Studio Tools for Git  to pull and push to the GIT server.
Everything was ok with PULL but  when i PUSH it have an error below,

```
An error was raised by libgit2. Category = Net (Error).
Remote error: access denied or repository not exported: /testing.git
```

http://postimg.org/image/tf07g89g1/

I Thought this error causes by permission but it was not.
I use GIT extension to push to GIT server and everything was ok.
Can some body please help me?

http://postimg.org/image/hraqzf9ox/

Comment: Please post the text of the error message in your question.

Comment: I realized that is a permission matter. VS2012 with Visual Studio Tools for Git can not make an athentication to GIT Server.But i dont know how to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is VS 2012 can not make an authentication via SSH althought i run putty SSH agent in background.
I hope this feature can be improved in the future.